# Chapter name on single page

Tags: chapters

I was wondering could anybody help me out, I would like to have one chapter heading alone in the centre of a page. All the other chapters will stay as normal, with the text on the same page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=40mm, bottom=40mm, left=40mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

%preambles

\chapter{introduction}
some text here
\section{name}
some text here

\chapter{background}
some text here
\section{name}
some text here

\chapter*{discussion}% I would like for this chapter heading to be centred on a single page and the section to go to next page
some text here
\section{name}
some text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Naphaneal, I have tried                                                                         \topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}                                                                                      \chapter*{\centering{name}}                                                               \vspace*{\fill}                                                                                        that's as far as my knowledge of latex goes, I am new this way of report writing

Comment: you might want to put a minimal working example inside your question.

Comment: I have updated my original message with a worked example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following achieves what you're looking for: Replace the instruction

```
\chapter*{discussion}
```

with

```
\part*{discussion}
\markboth{}{}
```

This will put the word "discussion" in the middle of the page, centered both horizontally and vertically.

After that, continue with `\chapter` and `\section` as usual.

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[vmargin=40mm, left=40mm, right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%preambles

\chapter{introduction}
some text here
\section{name}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{background}
some text here
\section{name}
\lipsum[1-5]

\part*{discussion}
%\markboth{}{}


\chapter{details}
some text here
\section{whatever}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks, I really appreciate your help